# FFMpeg geq filter proper documentation

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make sense of the geq filter since I couldn't find proper documentation for it.
I've noticed it's very advanced and can do alot of things and may accept different number of parameters in various cases.

For example , I saw an example that created a circular cut of a video using the geq filter that used 3 paramters ("geq=0:128:128").

Anyone knows where can I find proper documentation for this filter?

Comment: I believe this is the documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq

Comment: @MarkSetchell unfortently it's VERT limited and doesn't explain the different parameters and various combinations that are avaliable, specifically in my above example.

Comment: Mark's link points to the official documentation, which is as "proper" as it gets. If you want to learn about the expressions, you need to study [this documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)